# Does any beach in Sentosa Island in Singapore allow swimming after 7pm?

Tags: singapore, beaches, swimming, opening-hours, sentosa-island

I went to a beach in Sentosa Island in Singapore, namely Siloso beach, and I read that swimming was not allowed after 7pm on the sign pictured below. Does any beach on Sentosa Island in Singapore allow swimming after 7pm?

[image]

Comment: there are _hours_ for being in the water? (are those beaches on a private property?)

Comment: @njzk2 swimming hours are regulated indeed, and I have no idea whether it's private property. I also wonder whether it's lawful and the penalty if any of someone gets caught for "using the sea". If you ask me, they should focus on regulating individuals who pollute the sea rather than people who want to enjoy it, and definitely not penalize people who prefer to avoid UVs. I am much more concerned about skin cancer than drowning. If someone can't swim against the current, just float away and wait to be fished or run across some area with less current.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Zoinks, if you suddenly disappear should we notify the Singaporean Coast Guard to go look for you? Singapore has been making HNQ quite a bit thanks to your trip! Since you like doing a bunch of stuff at night, let me recommend Night Safari. Best evening attraction that I experienced during my short time there.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore Thanks, it's ok, you can let me float away, I would like to visit Batam anyway. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No**, they do not.  There are only three beaches on Sentosa (Tanjong, Palawan, Siloso) and they're all managed by the Sentosa Development Corporation with the same rules.

The reason you're not allowed to swim at night is because the beaches are artificial and there are strong currents right outside the line of buoys.  People who go beyond them [regularly get in trouble](https://theindependent.sg/man-suffers-near-death-experience-due-to-strong-rip-current-at-sentosa/), and at night when it's dark and there are no life guards this would be a likely death sentence.

Comment: in Singapore, you should assume all rules are implemented at all times

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150219/discussion-on-answer-by-lambshaanxy-does-any-beach-in-sentosa-island-in-singapor); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.